# Does enlightenment stack?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Does the monk buff enlightenment stack with other experience buffs? For example say you've got the rested bonus and an heirloom that gives 10% more experience gained, would this add up to 260% experience gained?
Or if you have the rested bonus would the 50% be calculated as 50% of 200, making the total 300%?
Or does enlightenment just not stack with rested/heirlooms at all?

Comment: I think the question shouldn't be 'does enlightenment stack'. It should rather be 'how does enlightenment stack'. All XP buffs as far as I know stack.

Comment: Yeah they do, I wasn't sure how they stacked but David B tested with science to answer that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Science!  61 dwarf monk vs 61 marshfang ripper

```
(10% guild perk, rested)
540 * 2.2 = 1188 xp ... (base + 10%) * 2
(10% guild perk, rested, 15% items)
540 * 2.5 = 1350 xp ... (base + 25%) * 2

(10% guild perk, rested, enlightened)
540 * 3.2 = 1728 xp ... (base + 60%) * 2
(10% guild perk, rested, enlightened, 15% items)
540 * 3.5 = 1890 xp ... (base + 75%) * 2
```

Everything stacks additively, except rested - which doubles everything.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, as I really should know this, but what's the 10% guild perk? Is it a perk from the guild reaching a certain level?

Comment: Fast Track rank 1 = 5% at guild level 1.  Fast Track rank 2 = 10% at guild level 6.  http://www.wowhead.com/spell=78632/fast-track